# Django - Q object search by data in an associated model

Tags: django, django-q

I have a Q object that queries my database that works something like this:

```
class EventSearchManager(models.Manager):

        q_objects = []

        terms = [term.strip() for term in search_terms.split()]

        today = date.today()

        if timeselect == "Today":
            first_day = today
            last_day = None

        for term in terms:
            search = (
                Q(name__icontains=term) | 
                Q(tags__label__icontains=term),
            )

            if first_day is not None:
                operators.update({'start_date__gte': first_day})
            if last_day is not None:
                operators.update({'start_date__lte': last_day})

            q_objects.append(Q(*search, **operators))

        qs = self.get_queryset()

        return qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_objects))
```

It works well, but I've just refactored the Events so that `start_date` exists in a separate `EventInstance` model (this way an event can have an indefinite amount of start dates).

Now I would like to adapt this search to return Event objects so that `operators.update({'start_date__gte': first_day})` references the `start_date` of all associated `EventInstance` objects. Is there an easy syntax adjustment I can make, or will I need to reconstruct this process entirely? Or am I simply asking too much of the Q object?

This is my EventInstance model which establishes the relationship:

```
class EventInstance(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.TimeField()
    recurring = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q objects are exactly the same as a normal filter condition. Since you can follow relationships in a filter condition, you can do it in a Q as well.

You don't show your models, but assuming the relation is just called `eventinstance`, you can do:

```
operators.update({'eventinstance__start_date__gte': first_day})
```